# How to I fix this Ionic Capacitor keyboard issue?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, plugins, ionic4, capacitor

I am developing a simple Ionic Capacitor app. I was trying to show/hide the keyboard depending on some use cases. After following the capacitor documentation for the keyboard, I could not get it to work. And now, I cannot build my app. I keep getting this error:

**[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "CapacitorKeyboard":
In Podfile:
CapacitorKeyboard (from `../../node_modules/@capacitor/keyboard`)
Specs satisfying the `CapacitorKeyboard (from` ../../node_modules/@capacitor/keyboard`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.**

I deleted my node_modules file and then ran npm install afterwards, but the error continues to come back. I also tried deleting `pod 'CapacitorKeyboard', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/keyboard'` from my Podfile, but it keeps coming back. How can I get fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the dependency from the angular.json file is the answer.